# Azure ServiceBus Queue save and read File byte[]

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am tring to store File byte[] to Azure ServiceBusQueue and read it back from Queue.

Here is my code to store file to queue.

```
var uploadedFile = new Byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length]; 

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

            var message = Utility.CreateBrokeredMessage(uploadedFile);


            var senderQueue = new QueueSender("tasksnotifications");

            if (senderQueue.SendMessage(message))
            {
                ResultText = "Your message has been submitted successfully";
                MessageTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                ResultText = "Your message is not submitted.";
            }
```

And Here is code for reading message from Queue.

```
// Process message from queue
             Console.WriteLine("Body: " + messageReceivedEventArgs.BrokeredMessage.GetBody<object>());

             Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + messageReceivedEventArgs.BrokeredMessage.MessageId);

             // Remove message from queue
             messageReceivedEventArgs.BrokeredMessage.Complete();
```

I am not sure if it is possible to store byte[] of file to Azure ServiceBus Queue, but the data is sent successfully.

Questions:
How do I read byte[] from BrokeredMessage object which I received from Queue?

Please share any useful links with this topic or if this question is already asked somewhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be to accomplish this by deserializing the message body as a `byte[]`:

```
// Process message from queue
Console.WriteLine("Body: " + messageReceivedEventArgs.BrokeredMessage.GetBody<byte[]>());
```

Note that the maximum size of a Service Bus message is 256 KB. See also [Service Bus Quotas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee732538.aspx).